# before_action extend from superclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have next definitions:

**ApplicationController:**

```
before_action :set_resource, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
...
private

def set_resource
...

OtherController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_resource, only: [:new_action1, :new_action2]
    ...
    def new_action1
    ....
    def new_action2
```

I expect **set_resource** method will be called before actions `edit, update, destroy,` `new_action1, new_action2`, but it right only for methods: `edit, update, destroy`

Comment: So what actually your question is?

Comment: why :set_resource not called for :new_action1, :new_action2\

Comment: @DavydovEugene you have defined :set_resource method as private so it can be in application controller . try by removing `private`

Comment: it's mistake, there are protected really

Answer (score 0):

I faced almost the same problem today while writing plugin for Redmine.
There is an issues_controller with callbacks in Redmine:

```
OtherController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_issue, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index]
end
```

And I added another action in module that is being included in issues_controller:

```
module IssuesControllerPatch
  def self.included(base)
    before_filter :find_issue, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :merge]
  end
end
```

What happened here is newly added filter for merge action gets called *after* authorize method, thus failing authorization.

To solve the problem, I overrode authorize method like that:

```
module IssuesControllerPatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

    base.class_eval do
      alias_method :default_authorize, :authorize
      alias_method :authorize, :authorize_with_merge
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def authorize_with_merge
      find_issue if params[:action] == "merge" && params[:controller] == "issues"
      default_authorize
    end
  end
end
```

Not quite elegant, but works like a charm. This should help you, as well.